# Laravel Clear Model Queries

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this code but I am not sure if is possible be more compact or I´m not sure if this is the way should looks this type of queries in laravel.

```
public function getRoleTransactionNameByID($id)
{

    $role_transaction= $this->model->select(
            'roles_transactions.id',
            'roles.id as role_id', 
            'roles.role_name', 
            'modules.module_name',
            'transactions.transaction_name', 
            'transactions.transaction_description',
            'roles_transactions.transaction_action_id',
            'transaction_actions.transaction_action_name',
            'roles_transactions.created_at',
            'roles_transactions.updated_at')

        ->join('roles', 'roles_transactions.role_id', '=', 'roles.id')
        ->join('transactions', 'roles_transactions.transaction_id', '=', 'transactions.id')
        ->join('transaction_actions', 'roles_transactions.transaction_action_id', '=', 'transaction_actions.id' )
        ->leftjoin('modules','transactions.module_id', '=', 'modules.id')

        ->where('roles_transactions.id', '=', $id)
        ->where('roles_transactions.deleted_at','=', null)

        ->orderby('roles.role_name', 'ASC')
        ->orderby('modules.module_name', 'ASC')
        ->orderby('transactions.transaction_name', 'ASC')

        ->get();

    return $role_transaction;
}
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: I think this is about as compact as you will get it given the query.